# SQL - how to concatenate one of the columns

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

MY SQL : I have a table that has 3 columns:

```
╔═════╦═════╦════════╗
║ ID1 ║ ID2 ║ ANSWER ║
╠═════╬═════╬════════╣
║   1 ║   2 ║      4 ║
║   1 ║   2 ║      5 ║
║   1 ║   4 ║      8 ║
╚═════╩═════╩════════╝
```

And i want a table that will look like that:

```
╔═════╦═════╦════════╗
║ ID1 ║ ID2 ║ ANSWER ║
╠═════╬═════╬════════╣
║   1 ║   2 ║ 4 + 5  ║
║   1 ║   4 ║ 8      ║
╚═════╩═════╩════════╝
```

Meaning: if i have different answers for id1&id2, i want them to be in one row with some separator (it can be + or something else) and only one row for each pair of id1,id2

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc..

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function with a `GROUP BY` to get the `Answer` values concatenated into the same row:

```
select id1,
  id2,
  group_concat(answer SEPARATOR ' + ') as Answer
from yourtable
group by id1,  id2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/170a6/3).

This produces the result:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | ANSWER |
----------------------
|   1 |   2 |  4 + 5 |
|   1 |   4 |      8 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned now that you are using `MySQL`, you can take advantage of `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, GROUP_CONCAT(Answer SEPARATOR ' + ') AnswerList
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1bb/4)
- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)